# Extend / Customize a doctrine's entity repository in Symfony

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, repository, entity

I need help with doctrine in Symfony, I'd like to extend/customize an entity repository... so I made a class in the Repository folder of the bundle (which didn't exist) but I don't know what else to do apart of extend the class from EntityRepository.

Here is the code:

```
<?php

class InvitadoRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function findOneByIdJoinedToCategory($id)
    {
        $query = $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery('
            SELECT p, c FROM AcmeStoreBundle:Product p
            JOIN p.category c
            WHERE p.id = :id'
        )->setParameter('id', $id);

        try {
            return $query->getSingleResult();
        } catch (\Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException $e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}

?>
```

So here is how it looks in my project:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/29094109/respositoryextend.tiff

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question is old, but if you or someone viewing this question doesn't know the answer yet, it is that you need to tell Doctrine to use your custom repository class for that entity.

Example from the [Symfony 2 Doctrine documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes) (using annotations; you can of course use YAML or XML if you prefer):

```
// src/Acme/StoreBundle/Entity/Product.php
namespace Acme\StoreBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Acme\StoreBundle\Repository\ProductRepository")
 */
class Product
{
    //...
}
```